# React Native: Unable to resolve module http

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I Can't solve this error, i got it after upgrading to the latest NPM version 0.72.1. and changing node version from 16.4.3 to 18.16.1 This is the Log:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module http from /Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/@smithy/node-http-handler/dist-cjs/node-http-handler.js: http could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../../node_modules
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.NodeHttpHandler = exports.DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = void 0;
> 4 | const protocol_http_1 = require("@smithy/protocol-http");
    |                                                   ^
  5 | const querystring_builder_1 = require("@smithy/querystring-builder");
  6 | const http_1 = require("http");
  7 | const https_1 = require("https");
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:472:35)
    at Graph._processModule (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:260:38)
    at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:371:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Graph._processModule (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:321:5)
    at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/toms/Documents/VolleyballApp/volleyball/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:371:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
```

I am running

- react-native version: 0.72.1
- Node version: 18.16.1

I tried clearing cache, reinstalling node_modules + pods but it didn't work. Anyone know what it might be?

Comment: Found the issue, it is caused by the @aws-sdk/client-s3 package: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4877